# nginx - Limit client_max_body_size based on content_type

Tags: nginx

I am looking to limit the size of the `client body` based on the content type in nginx.

```
location / {
    if ($content_type = "application/json") {
            client_max_body_size 1M;
            client_body_buffer_size 512K;
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

I've tried the above `if` condition which fails with below error.

```
nginx: [emerg] "client_max_body_size" directive is not allowed here
```

I have also tried using this without any effect

```
location ~* ^.+\.json {
   client_max_body_size 1M;
   client_body_buffer_size 512K;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use a `map` directive in your http block but outside any server blocks.

```
map $http_content_type $upload_limit {
    default 0;
    application/json 1M;
}
```

This sets the second variable based upon the value of the first, so by default it'll be 0 but if content type header is application/json it'll be 1M.

Now you use your custom variable like this `client_max_body_size $upload_limit;`